# how to print on an ethernet printer over the internet

Tags: internet, port-forwarding, network-printer

I have a speedport w920v router and I have connected an ethernet printer to it. I have also forwarded the correct port to the ip address of the printer and I can ping the IP address but I can't connect to the printer over the internet (I can connect to the printer locally using the local IP address)

The printer is HP Officejet 4500

Answer (score 3):

It's just not a matter of doing anything on the printer side of the network. It's that most of the networks you will use when you are away from home won't forward this kind of traffic onto the public internet in the first place.

You'll have better luck by setting up a VPN into your home network.